# Move a file from one SFTP folder to another SFTP Folder from Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline created in Data Factory that brings a file from a folder connected to an SFTP and leaves it in an ADSL container (Gen2). What I need is that once this process is finished, move the file from the SFTP source folder to another called "Procesados" but from Azure Data Factory, is it possible?

[image]

Thanks!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You just set up a copy activity with source as where the file is in your picture and sink as your desired destination.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the xlsx file type does not exist in the destination, so I cannot perform that operation.

Comment: If you just want to move a file, you should choose the binary type, not excel. Excel is if you want to get a dataset that can be inserted into other destination other than excel file. 3

Comment: Excellent, with that I was able to solve it, just keep in mind that both source and destination must be binary for it to work. Thank you very much!